# How to get react noUiSlider min max values on update?

Tags: reactjs, nouislider

I am trying to use noUiSlider to filter my results. I used noUiSlider component to show slider. Slider is showing but i am not able to get min max values on slide. I want to show integer min max values in text box and use them for filter.

this is how i import noUislider

```
import '../../node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';
import Nouislider from 'react-nouislider';

<Nouislider
range={{min: 0, max: 800000}}
start={[20000, 500000]}
onSlide={this.onChangeSlide.bind(this)}
ref="NoUiSlider"
tooltips/>
```

I used onchange slide method to get values but its not working

```
onChangeSlide(){
   console.log(this.refs.NoUiSlider.slider.get()) // logs the value
}
```

How can i get values Please help me

Comment: working for me can you try to reproduce?

Comment: where should i write this: onChangeSlide()?

Comment: I am writing this in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onSlide` callback is already giving you a data, you just need add variable to get the data.

```
onSlide={(data)=> console.log(data)}
```

check [this](https://github.com/algolia/react-nouislider/issues/7#issuecomment-359200381)

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-puujrv)

You can just add `onChangeSlide` as normal function. if you want to get data inside that.

```
 onChangeSlide(data) {
    console.log(data) // logs the value
  }


 <Nouislider
        range={{ min: 0, max: 800000 }}
        start={[20000, 500000]}
        onSlide={this.onChangeSlide.bind(this)}
        ref="NoUiSlider"
        tooltips />
```

Comment: thanks it works for me.I was adding function in wrong place.

Comment: is there any way i can get the integer values on tooltip?

Comment: @Vinay you mean? and why you want to do that?

Comment: when i slide values showing on tooltip is 120.00 i want 120.

Comment: you can use `var a = new Number('120.00');`

Comment: @Vinay no idea about that you can ask here https://github.com/algolia/react-nouislider